# Cut a slice at z in 3D plot in Mathematica

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I am trying to cut a slice on z axis in a ContourPlot3d but I am unable to see any change in the slice plane. I am using the following code:

```
ySlice2 = ContourPlot3D[z == -1.5*10^-13, {x, 0, g}, {y, -2, 2}, {z,-1*10^-12, 0},ContourStyle -> Opacity[0.5, Lighter@Red], Mesh -> None, ImageSize -> Large, AspectRatio -> Full]
```

I need cut at different values of z axis and then later add this to other Plot3D using show. Please help.

Regards,
Raghu

Comment: Use [`ClipPlanes`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ClipPlanes.html).

Comment: Can you please give me the code snippet to use ClipPlanes to cut z-axis? I see that ClipPlanes is used with Graphics3D but how can I fix the x,y and z ranges and then cut a plane at z = constant.

Answer (score 2):

Does this do what you want?

```
Manipulate[
  ContourPlot3D[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 1, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, 
    ClipPlanes -> InfinitePlane[{0, 0, Z}, {{0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0}}]],
  {{Z, 0}, -1, 1}]
```

[image]